# getting related fields in serialzer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a movie database with about a dozen tables but want to work with 3. I am using Django 3

```
 class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
 
 class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  
 class Review(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="customer_review")
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name="movie_review")
```

Now, I want to get all reviews like this:

```
  id      name     title
```

where id is the auto PK from Review table, name from Customer and title from Movie.

```
 class ReviewSerializer(serailizers.ModelSerailizer):
    class Meta:
          model = Review
          fields = ["id","name","title"]
```

how can I possibly state name and title in the list of fields? I thought I could do

```
         fields = ["id","customer__name","movie__title"]
```

but it is crushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a related name in serializer you must use a . instead of __
And its good to declare your field in serializer like:

```
class ReviewSerializer(serailizers.ModelSerailizer):
    customer_name = serializers.CharField(source='customer.name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ["id","customer_name",...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create that field using either `source` or `SerializerMethodField`.
Both are possible, but the former one is simple. But you can get more complicated value using the latter.

```
class ReviewSerializer(serailizers.ModelSerailizer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='customer.name')
    # title = serializers.CharField(source='movie.title') 
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ["id", "name", "title"]

    def get_title(self, obj)
        return obj.movie.title
```